# Python snippet duplicate lines I have chosen

Tags: python

I want to grabs specified sections from several files.

All my files is structured as the following but have difference object data:

```
some lines
ObjectAlias apple
some lines
Begin
some lines
End
some lines
ObjectAlias pear
some lines
Begin
some lines
End
...
```

Assume I have my a list of my files, a list of specified "ObjectAlias" patterns and a function:

```
def dummyFunc (fileList, objList):
    dummy = ""

    for file in fileList:
        with open(file, "r") as infile:
            Tag = False
            for line in infile:
                for obj in objList:
                    if line.find("ObjectAlias " + obj + "\n") !=-1:
                        Tag = True
                    if Tag:
                        dummy += line
                    if line.find("End") != -1:
                        Tag = False
    return (dummy)
```

This code give me result like this:

```
...
ObjectAlias cherry
ObjectAlias cherry
ObjectAlias cherry
ObjectAlias cherry
Begin
Begin
Begin
Begin
same lines
same lines
same lines
same lines
End
...
```

This is what I expected:

```
...
ObjectAlias apple
some lines
Begin
some lines
End
ObjectAlias cherry
some lines
Begin
some lines
End
...
```

What I did wrong with the code?
As I test, the similar code works fine with a single file and a single object , but not work when use list as input, if objList has 5 items, the result will be 5x each line.

Any help is welcome.

**EDIT:Explain more clearly**

FileA:

```
some lines
ObjectAlias apple
some lines
Begin
some lines about apple
End
some lines
ObjectAlias pear
some lines
Begin
some lines about pear
End
some lines
ObjectAlias orange
some lines
Begin
some lines about orange
End
some lines
```

FileB:

```
some lines
ObjectAlias lemon
some lines
Begin
some lines about lemon
End
some lines
ObjectAlias peach
some lines
Begin
some lines about peach
End
some lines
ObjectAlias tomato
some lines
Begin
some lines about tomato
End
some lines
```

Want to filter pear and peach into new file, so it is:

```
ObjectAlias pear
Begin
some lines about pear
End
ObjectAlias peach
Begin
some lines about peach
End
```

With iownthegame's help, I modify my code into:

```
def dummyFunc (fileList, objList):
    dummy = ""

    for file in fileList:
        with open(file, "r") as infile:
            Tag = False
            for line in infile:
                for obj in objList:
                    objString = "ObjectAlias " + obj
                    if objString in line:
                        dummy += line
                        break
                    elif "Begin" in line:
                        Tag = True
                        break
                    elif "End" in line:
                        dummy += line
                        Tag = False
                        break
                if Tag:
                    dummy += line
    return (dummy)

income = ["e:/FileA", "e:/FileB"]
filter = ["pear", "peach"]
with open("e:/Result", "w") as f:
    f.write(dummyFunc(income, filter))
```

But I get this output:

```
Begin
some lines about apple
End
ObjectAlias pear
Begin
some lines about pear
End
Begin
some lines about orange
End
Begin
some lines about lemon
End
ObjectAlias peach
Begin
some lines about peach
End
Begin
some lines about tomato
End
```

I am absolutely beginner, what I did wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a `break` when you find an `obj` in the each rather than keep finding and concatenating the output

**update:** since you need to filter out  the lines between ObjectAlias and Begin, so you need one more `state` to record what is done during the processing.

I modify your **Tag** to record different state, initialises with None Tag, once meet **ObjectAlias** line, goes to `start` Tag, once meet **Begin** line, goes to `begin` Tag, once meet **End** line, goes to None Tag. So if you meet some lines earlier than than `begin` Tag, we don't print them. Another situation is when we meet **Begin** line or **End** line before **ObjectAlias** line starts, we also don't count.

Hope this solution may help.

```
def dummyFunc (fileList, objList):
    dummy = ""

    for file in fileList:
        with open(file, "r") as infile:
            Tag = None
            for line in infile:
                for obj in objList:
                    objString = "ObjectAlias " + obj
                    if objString in line:
                        Tag = "start"
                        dummy += line
                        break
                    elif "Begin" in line:
                        if Tag == "start":
                                Tag = "begin"
                        break
                    elif "End" in line:
                        if Tag == "begin":
                                Tag = None
                                dummy += line
                        break
                if Tag == "begin":
                    dummy += line
    return (dummy)
```

Comment: :Great help. Curiosity, if I don't need the lines bewteen ObjectAlias and Begin either, is it possible?

Comment: No, there is no "End" line in the end of each section.

Comment: what's your expected output? the above you want is actually similar to the original file

Comment: Your code did not inculde "End" line in each object section, just like the output in my thread. Go a step further, ObjectAlias line + Begin to End will be perfect.

Comment: Sorry for bother, still can't get that output, and I have update my question, I think it is more clearly.

Comment: :Perfect one! I think I can understand it.